# Rails Tutorial Login/Logout Form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication, form-for

I'm following this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login
to build a webapp to monitor user login. I managed to get users to properly login but there are some problems even when i followed all of Michael Hartl's code.

1. I can paste a user's url into the browser and it will still pull it up (so no login  actually required). ie: type in "localhost:3000/users/1" and it takes me to the page regardless if logged in or not.
2. I have inside my app/views/layouts folder a number of files (see below for code) to display stuff when the user logs in or is not logged in. The problem is everything gets displayed regardless if the user logs in or out on any page (ie: the header bar should not say "logout" in it if user isn't logged in and is on the login page) Pic of Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzRLj.png
3. When I go to click the logout tab after logging in, I get this error:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5umj.png

I'm confused as to why these errors occur since I followed Hartl's tutorial exactly as he said you should.

Code:

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root 'sessions#new'
  get '/home', to:'sessions#new'
  get '/search', to:'pages#search'
  get '/people', to:'pages#people'
  get '/profilepage', to:'pages#profilepage'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy' ## this breaks stuff idk why
  #get '/logout' => :destroy, to: 'sessions#new' #This "works" but has the issue of #1
  resources :users

end
```

app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
            <% if logged_in? %>
              <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
              <li>
                    <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
                  </li>
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <% if false %>
        <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sessions Controller:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController

      def new
      end

      def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
          log_in user
          redirect_to user
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        log_out
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

Sessions Helper:

```
    module SessionsHelper

      # Logs in the given user.
      def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
      end

      # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
      def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
      end

      def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
      end

      def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
      end

      def destroy
        log_out
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

Rake Routes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is correct, I have tried it myself and it worked fine for me so clearly you have something in your code that is messed up :) Please review your code and provide your `rake routes` output here in case of any problems and your console's output as well.

Comment: i'm really confused as to why the code isn't working however. I literally copied and pasted everything from chapters 6-8 on the tutorial and it still breaks

Comment: You have 2 #destroy methods: in SessionsHelper and SessionsController. I see differences in your code and the actual code in the tutorial so keep reviewing. May the force be with you :)

Comment: Ok so i deleted the sessions helper thanks for the help. However, the problem 3 is still not fixed. It still has that error of not finding /logout routes

Comment: Try `def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end`

Comment: Check your routes. You have sessions#new in 4 different places! `get 'sessions/new'`, `get 'users/new'`, `get '/home', to:'sessions#new'`, ` get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137296/discussion-between-joe-b-and-jedi).